# Webpack code splitting strange naming

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

So I've been working on a little side project for a few days now familiarizing myself with webpack. I've gotten almost everything to work the way I want but I the naming convention on webpack split chunks is very strange, and I feel like I'm not doing something quite right.

Currently I have all my Javascript exporting to **content\js[name].bundle.js** which works fine until I start using ensure.

For example, my main module is called app, so the final destination for app is currently **content\js\app.bundle.js** however when I use ensure it creates a file like **1.content\js\1.bundle.js**. I'd like to get it to output to something like **content\js\1.bundle.js** or something similar. If I can at least drop that 1 prefix then I'd be in good shape I think for what I'd like to do...

Apparently I'm not able to post images until I gain more rep, but here is my output and current webpack config file.

I appreciate the help!

```html
Hash: 23e616429710d37754d3
Version: webpack 1.13.1
Time: 12793ms
                        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
     content\js\app.bundle.js  3.16 kB       0  [emitted]  app
     1.content\js\1.bundle.js  15.1 kB       1  [emitted]
  content\js\vendor.bundle.js  4.31 MB       2  [emitted]  vendor
   content\css\app.styles.css  6.27 kB       0  [emitted]  app
content\css\vendor.styles.css   463 kB       2  [emitted]  vendor
                   index.html  5.19 kB          [emitted]
   [0] multi app 28 bytes {0} [built]
   [0] multi vendor 88 bytes {2} [built]
    + 455 hidden modules
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
        + 2 hidden modules
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
        + 2 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
        + 20 hidden modules
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
        + 7 hidden modules
```

```js
    var path = require('path');
    var webpack = require('webpack');
    var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

    // Webpack Plugins
    var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
    var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
    var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

    // Figure out what mode we're running in
    var mode   = process.env.NODE_ENV;

    if (mode == 'production') {
        console.log('Building for production...');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Building for development...');
    }

    // Define some paths that we'll use throughout the application
    var pathBaseOutput = path.join(__dirname, 'public');
    var pathEntryApp = path.join(__dirname, 'app');
    var pathJsOutput = 'content/js/';//path.join('content', 'js');
    var pathCssOutput = path.join('content', 'css');
    var pathIndexOutput = pathBaseOutput;

    // App webpack
    var app_pack = {};

    // Add the entries for our app
    app_pack['entry'] = {
        // The app itself
        'app': [ path.join(pathEntryApp , 'app.client')],
        // The vendor modules we want to abstract out
        'vendor': [ 'jquery', 'react', 'react-bootstrap', 'react-dom', 'bootstrap-loader', 'tether' ]
    }

    // Define the output directory of the javascript files
    app_pack['output'] = {
        path: pathBaseOutput,
        filename: path.join(pathJsOutput, '[name].bundle.js')
    }

    // Define any extra module loaders we might be interested in
    app_pack['module'] = {
        loaders: [
            // Inject css
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader')
            },
            // Process and inject SASS
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader')
            },
            // Process and inject .woff2 fonts
            {
                test: /\.woff2?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader'
            },
            // Process and inject .tff, .eot, and .svg files
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader'
            },
            // Transform JSX in .jsx files
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: [ 'es2015', 'react' ]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.hbs$/,
                loader: "handlebars"
            }
        ]
    }

    // Define where modules should be resolved from
    app_pack['resolve'] = {
        // Allow require('./blah') to require blah.jsx
        extensions: [ '', '.js', '.jsx' ],
        // The root of our web modules
        root: [
            path.resolve('./app/modules'),
        ],
        // Allow requiring modules from npm
        modulesDirectories: [
            'node_modules'
        ]
    }

    // Define what plugins we want to use
    app_pack['plugins'] = [
        // Create a vendor chunk for all our vendor code
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', path.join(pathJsOutput, '[name].bundle.js'), Infinity),
        // Resolve $, and jQuery so that modules that use them can resolve to require('jquery')
        // Note: This does NOT expose them to the global browser accessible namespace
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            '$': 'jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery'
        }),
        // Extract CSS files to a seperate place
        new ExtractTextPlugin(path.join(pathCssOutput, '[name].styles.css'), { allChunks: true }),
        // Pass the node environment down the webpack
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin([
            'NODE_ENV'
        ]),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin( [pathCssOutput, pathJsOutput, path.join(pathIndexOutput, 'index.html')] ),
        new webpack.BannerPlugin('Copyright 2016 Brandon Garling. Released under the MIT license'),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Taskie',
            template: 'app/index.hbs',
            hash: true
        })
    ];

    // Allow postcss using autoprefixer
    app_pack['postcss'] = [ autoprefixer ];

    /*
    * Mode specific injections
    */

    // Production
    if (mode == 'production') {
        // Add plugins
        app_pack['plugins'].push(
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        );
        // Search for equal or similar files and deduplicate them in the output.
        // This comes with some overhead for the entry chunk, but can reduce file size effectively.
        app_pack['plugins'].push(
            new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
        )
    }
    // Other (Development)
    else {
        // Add source maps inline
        app_pack['devtool'] = '#inline-source-map';
        // Add plugins
    }


    module.exports = app_pack;
```

Comment: When it comes to code splitting, you do not need take care how wried the chunk name is. Webpack will handle the chunks request for you, which means you do not need add a script tag for the chunks like bundles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I had to add the following to the output property of my app_pack:

```
chunkFilename: path.join(pathJsOutput, '[name].[id].bundle.js')
```

Apparently I just didn't look hard enough, it was right in front of my face on the docs located here: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

You are setting a path with backslashes as `output.filename` option. Use `output.path` to set the destination folder and `output.filename` for the actual filename only.

Comment: That works but it makes it more difficult to export my css and html to the correct folders. I was looking for a way to modify the naming of how these chunk filenames are emitted.